# Why am I getting error: object doesn't support this property or method for GetPivotData in excel VBA

Tags: excel, parameters, runtime-error, vba

Please see the code below, I cant figure out what I am doing wrong...

```
Dim rngItem As Range

For k = 1 To MonthStart ' looping through all of the months
            'On Error Resume Next
            Set rngItem = ActiveCell. _
               pvTable.getpivotdata(" 17-Sep", "Product_Description", "red wine")
```

I think the problem might be that I don't understand exactly how to put the arguments in the getpivotdata function. Product description and 17 - sep are the headings of the columns and red wine is in the product description column and I want to find the corresponding number in the 17 - sep column in the same row as that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure why you have ActiveCell in there. You are trying to set a range object so need to return a range. If you are after a value use a different variable type.

Comment: Dim i as Long: i =  pvTable.getpivotdata(" 17-Sep", "Product_Description", "red wine")   Check the syntax by recording a macro when selecting that cell from the pivot.

Comment: More info here: http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot06.html